# Firebase's getAuth() across multiple urls

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firebase

I have a chrome extension that uses firebase.  I want to enable the user to stay logged in across multiple websites; however, firebases's getAuth() appears to be url specific (ie if the user logs into the chrome app on one website it will return null when the user transitions to another website).  Does anyone know an alternative to getAuth or a way to make getAuth work in this use-case?

Comment: There's no way to share cookies or local storage between sites in a browser, as this is a security risk. Therefore, nothing you store locally will be available to another site. Thus, you'd need to [sign your own tokens](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html#section-custom) and either pass them via the URL (insecure) or contact the server open each new site to retrieve the token. Instead, you'd probably be ahead to step back and look at the bigger picture. What is the use case you're really trying to solve? This probably isn't the best solution.

Comment: After further digging I see that chrome does enable you to have the equivalent of local storage for your extension via chrome.storage, so I can store the encrypted user information.